# QTreeView/QHeaderView resize only first column to stretch and interactive both

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTreeView which has 5 columns. The requirement is to stretch only the first column but all the 5 columns should be resizable by user(i.e. they can be interactive as well) also. So I wrote the following code:

```
 int numCols = myModel->columnCount();
    for(int i=0;i<numCols;i++)
    {
       myQTreeView->resizeColumnToContents(i);
       if(i==0)
          {    
             myQTreeView->header()->setResizeMode(i,QHeaderView::Stretch);
          }
       else
          {  
             myQTreeView->header()->setResizeMode(i,QHeaderView::Interactive);
          }
     }
```

But this does not work as expected for 1st column. Although the 1st column stretches but it is not resizable/interactive like rest of the columns. Hence I want to add stretch+interactive for the 1st column. Rest of the 4 columns might as well be interactive only.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum) for `QHeaderView::ResizeMode`, when the mode has been set to `QHeaderView::Stretch`...

> The size cannot be changed by the user or programmatically.

So, no, I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want using the standard APIs.

You could try setting the resize mode to `QHeaderView::Custom` and overriding the various mouse event handlers in the `QHeaderView` by either installing an event filter on the existing `QHeaderView` or by creating your own class inheriting from `QHeaderView` and installing an instance of it in your view via `QTreeView::setHeader`.